# When does $((A/P)[x])_{\bar{Q}} \simeq ((A/P)_P[x])_{\bar{Q}} $ hold?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing, quotient-spaces, localization

Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring, consider $A[x]$, let $Q$ be a maximal ideal in $A[x]$, does hold that for the prime ideal $P:= A \cap Q$

$$((A/P)[x])_{\bar{Q}}  \simeq ((A/P)_P[x])_{\bar{Q}}$$

where $\bar{Q} := Q \mod PA[x]$. Does a formal proof involve universal property? Is there any intuition behind it? At first glance $(A/P)_P$ seems (actually is) bigger, hence if the isomorphism holds it should be thanks to the localization in $\bar{Q}$.

Any help or proof would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the isomorphism as? How are you localising $A/P$ wrt $P$? Are you considering $A/P$ as an $A$-module? Are the outermost localisations as $A[x]/PA[x]$-modules?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani yes